# Adding a new modem connection from code in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, connection, gprs

is there a way to add a new modem connection (GPRS) from code in C# (CF 3.5)? I've tried using OpenNetCF's ConnectionManager, but there doesn't seem to be an indirect way to do so.

In other words, I want to do what we can do in:
Start - Settings - Connections - Connections - Add a new modem connection
in Windows Mobile programatically.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you know any way to set password and username of a connection to GPRS in Windows Mobile from code?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add a new connection in "My ISP" thanks to ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration method and using this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="CM_GPRSEntries">
    <characteristic type="internet">
      <parm name="DestId" value="{ADB0B001-10B5-3F39-27C6-9742E785FCD4}" />
      <parm name="Phone" value="internet" />
      <parm name="UserName" value="internet" />   
      <parm name="Password" value="internet" />
      <parm name="Domain" value="" />
      <characteristic type="DevSpecificCellular">
         <parm name="GPRSInfoValid" value="1" />
         <parm name="GPRSInfoAccessPointName" value="internet" />
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

But it seems like this method needs some kind of commit because when i want to use IE - it doesn't work. I need to go to: Start - Settings - Connections - Connections, select my connection, edit (with no changes) and save - then it connects. Any ideas what to do in this situation?